# Can I get user id from mvc 3 web app in console app?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, console-application

I need to get user id from asp.net mvc 3 app in console app. Here is my code: (mvc)

```
public class MembershipRepository : IMembershipRepository
{
    public Guid GetUserId(string name)
    {
        var providerUserKey = Membership.GetUser(name).ProviderUserKey; // HttpException
        if (providerUserKey != null)
            return (Guid)providerUserKey;
        throw new NullReferenceException("user with this username does't exist");
    }
}
```

(console) code:

```
ninjectKernel.Bind<IMembershipRepository>().To<MembershipRepository>();
var membershipRepository = ninjectKernel.Get<IMembershipRepository>();
Guid userId = membershipRepository.GetUserId("admin");
```

HttpException: Unable to connect to the Sql server database.

Before the exception occures the window pops up: This program has compatibility problems (microsoft sql seqver 2008 and 2008 r2).
I have sql server 2012 installed.

Besides, it's only a small chunk of code. Before I'm trying to get userId I use other repositories to add data to the database and it works: when I check the table contents it's full of new entries.

How do I need to change the code? Mabby there is some other way to get userId in console app?

Thanks!

**Edits:**

App.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add
       name="WebStoreConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0; DataBase=WebStore;
          AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Aleksey\repos\working_copy\WebStore\WebStore\App_Data\WebStore.mdf;
          Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30"
          providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
    />
 </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exception occured because in MembershipRepository I used built-in Membership provider to return Users. I changed the impementation to work with data context:

```
public class MembershipRepository : IMembershipRepository
{
    private readonly WebStoreDataContext _dataContext;

    public MembershipRepository(WebStoreDataContext dataContext)
    {
        _dataContext = dataContext;
    }

    public IEnumerable<User> GetUsers()
    {
        return _dataContext.Users;
    }

    public Guid GetUserId(string name)
    {
        return _dataContext.Users.Where(u => u.UserName == name).Select(u => u.UserId).Single();
    }
}
```

everything works, and I doesn't need to use web request)

So, you can create new instance of MembershipRepository or instance of YourAppNameDataContext (and workd directly with data context)

Answer (score 0):

why not have a public method on your controler, and create a web request in your console app to call the method?

okay, it is fairly generic.

first you need an action menthod on your controller that takes some params

```
    [HttpPost]
    public guid MyActionMethod(string name)
    {

    }
```

Then you need to create a web request that calls the method

```
       UTF8Encoding encoding = new UTF8Encoding();

       string messageBody = "name=myName"
       byte[] requestBody = encoding.GetBytes(messageBody);

       HttpWebRequest WRequest;

        CredentialCache myCredCache = new CredentialCache();
        myCredCache.Add(new Uri(targetUrl), "NTLM", (NetworkCredential) CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials);

        WRequest = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("http://servername/controllerName/MyActionMethod/?" + messageBody);

        WRequest.Credentials = myCredCache;
        WRequest.UnsafeAuthenticatedConnectionSharing = true;
        WRequest.PreAuthenticate = false;
        WRequest.Method = "POST";
        WRequest.Timeout = 10000;
        WRequest.ContentLength = request.Length;
        WRequest.SendChunked = true;

        using (Stream requestStream = WRequest.GetRequestStream())
            requestStream.Write(requestBody, 0, requestBody.Length);
```

I think thats right? check the web request, I copied it from some come I have, and had to reconstruct it as it was in a number of diff methods.

Comment: one question: how to get userId??? action method should have string parameter (name) and retrieve Guid (userId).